# Using SVN as total backup solution for multiple OS sharing data disk

Tags: linux, partitioning, backup, svn

I just installed two Linux OS's on one laptop, dual-booting. I keep my important data on an EXT3 partition that I share between the OS's.

I was using CrashPlan for automated backup, but I suspect it would be sloppy if not a downright bad idea to install CrashPlan client on multiple OS's and ask it to back up the same data disk.  (I assume the two installations of CrashPlan would have a conflicting opinion of "where they left off" at the most recent backup). Same is probably true for many other automated sync/backup systems, e.g. Dropbox.  So, I'd like to replace CrashPlan with a more versatile, more predictable, more DIY backup solution that lets me back up the shared data partition regardless

Since I am paying for webspace, one good option might be to install Subversion and periodically backup selected folders from the command line. Will this work independent of which operating system I'm using at the time? (In other words, is all the information SVN needs to do its work contained within the backup file directory and/or the repository---*not* somewhere else on my local Linux installation)?

Comment: You might want to check out [Git as a backup and Version Control System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576198/git-as-a-backup-and-version-control-system). ~ Don't. Version control != backup.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the backup client - the "subversion" client keeps the subversion information underneath the directories being backed up, while fsvs (which is more suitable for versioning configs) puts the backup information under /etc).

I agree with @IObO that version control is not ideal for backup (its slow and designed for different purpose), although its certainly a lot better then nothing, and viable if you only have a small amount of stuff.    Maybe have a look at BackupPC (for Windows and Linux) or rsync or rsnapshot (not used this with Windows, maybe you can use cygwin ?)

Also, I'd suggest against command line backups as they tend to get out of date because its a manual process.

Comment: No need to backup from Windows---just want a solution for my Linux installations.
Looks like BackupPC stores configuration files in /etc/ as well. I think I'll set something up with rsync or rsnapshot. I didn't mean that I'd be manually backing up from command line; I want to set up a couple of scripts to run as cron jobs.  Thanks for the info re: versioning systems.